# CMenu URL attribute usage when dynamicaly adding menu items?

Tags: yii, cmenu

Not sure if it's a best practice, but we wish to have a **menu** on a **layout view** and pass as **URL parameter** a value that should retrieve some data.

The menu would be something like:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>districtA</li>
<li>districtB</li>
<li>districtC</li>
</ul>
```

So something like:

```
'url'=>array('/event/getEventsByDistrict', 'district'=>id),
```

Is there a better way to do it?

I mean, by doing like this, I believe, if a new district gets added to the database, then we should edit the menu by hand, placing the corresponding id there ? Isn't there a way to retrieve that id from the database, so that, every time the menu is rendered, we may be sure that that new item will link to the appropriate id of that new (just added district?) ?

Does this makes sense to you?

It seems that the only way could be that of creating a wrapper class or something ?

Perhaps districts are NOT a good example, they don't change often, but let's imagine something that changes often.

Please advice

Comment: You want a menu item that links to the latest district, or a menu that links to every district?

Comment: @Örs I've updated my question. Each menu item should retrieve ALL events of a given district. By that's a controller decision, it could be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work, assuming your `District` model has a `name` property.

```
$districts = DistrictModel::model()->findAll();
$menu = array();
foreach($districts as $district) $menu[] = array('label'=>$district->name, 'url'=>array('event/getEventsByDistrict', 'district'=>$district->id));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items'=>$menu
));
```

Comment: Ors, thanks, that seems to be a nice way to go. Not tested yet, but I will give it a try.